# Custom Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> to execute callback on double click in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following implementation:

```
class CustomTableRow<T> implements CallBack <Tableview<T> TableRow<T>>{
    private T selectedItem;

    public CustomTableRow(T selectedItem){
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    @Override
    public TableRow<T> call(TableView<T> param){
        TableRow<T> row = new TableRow<>΄
        row.setOnMouseClicked(event ->{
            if (!row.isEmpty()){
                try{
                    //Using BeanUtils.copyProperties();
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have a class that uses this CustomTableRow

```
class SomeClass{

    private Tableview myTableView;
    private MyCustomModelClass selectedItem;

    private setUpTableView(){
        selectedItem = new MyCustomModelClass();
        tableView.setRowFactory(new CustomTableRow<MyCustomModelClass>(selectedItem));    
    }


    private thisNeedsToBeExecutedOnRowDoubleClick(){
    }
}
```

To make things worst this CustomTableRow is used by other TableViews that don't need to implement the double click function.

Should I create two different CustomTableRow classes or is it possible to pass a callback function (like javascript) to execute when double click is detected and selectedItem is of MyCustomModelClass type? I am using java version 8 Update 45.

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you wanting `CustomTableRow` to implement double-click handling (but with a different action for different tables)? Or does `CustomTableRow` provide different functionality, and you want to add double click handling to some instances of it (but not all)?

Comment: The first thing you said. I want to implement double click capability but for different tables or CustomModelClass(I have many). I want to be able to call a method of SomeClass(a controller class) when a row is double clicked

Answer (score 0):

Define your `CustomTableRow` to take a `Consumer<T>` as a parameter, and invoke that object's `accept(...)` method when the double-click occurs. Here's the basic idea (I renamed `CustomTableRow` to `DoubleClickTableRowFactory` as I think it's a better description of what this does):

```
public class MouseClickTableRowFactory<T> 
  implements Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> {

    private final Consumer<T> doubleClickHandler ;
    private final int numClicks ;

    public MouseClickTableRowFactory(Consumer<T> doubleClickHandler, int numClicks) {
        this.doubleClickHandler = doubleClickHandler ;
        this.numClicks = numClicks ;
    }

    public MouseClickTableRowFactory(Consumer<T> doubleClickHandler) {
        // default to double-click...
        this(doubleClickHandler, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public TableRow<T> call(TableView<T> tv) {

        TableRow<T> row = new TableRow<>();
        row.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == numClicks && ! row.isEmpty()) {
                doubleClickHandler.accept(row.getItem());
            }
        });
        return row ;
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
public class SomeClass {

    private TableView<MyCustomModelClass> myTableView ;

    // ...

    private void setupTable() {
        myTableView.setRowFactory(
          // invokes rowDoubleClicked when user double-clicks on a row:
          new MouseClickTableRowFactory<>(this::rowDoubleClicked));

        // for single click, do
        // myTableView.setRowFactory(
        //  new MouseClickTableRowFactory(item -> { ... }, 1));
        // ...
    }

    private void rowDoubleClicked(MyCustomModelClass item) {
        // handle double-click on row displaying item
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find Consumer object docs. How about single clicks on all other tables? just have an else statement? Where can I find info about Consumer and accept function?

Comment: [`Consumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) is in `java.util.function`. You could pass a parameter into the row factory implementation specifying how many clicks you wanted... updated answer with that option.